# Use same function as "standard" one and as an event handler

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I have a function

```
function foo(event, var1) {
    // do something...
}
```

I am using this function in some event bubbling, but I also need to use as a normal function that's called by me from my code. `Event` parameter is used only with event bubbling. What to pass to `event` from my own code to get this to work?

P.s. I have a feeling this is not good design, but that's the way things turned out. We'll change it when time comes, but for now, it's gotta stay like this.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to pass `null`. I so rarely use `null` in javascript that it simply seemed out of place.

Comment: So, what's the problem here, exactly? If you pass `null` for `event` (or anything), then you'll be able to get `var1`. If you don't want to pass `null` then what about using `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `var1` is always passed to the function then you should switch the order of params.

If your function goes `foo(var1, event)` then it doesn't matter if `event` is empty, the function will still work. This has to do with the concept of [optional params](http://javascript.about.com/od/3functions/a/fun04.htm).